# What level and what strategy is recommended to get the "Beryllium" achievement

Tags: achievements, a-virus-named-tom

I'm trying to get the following in achievement in A Virus Named Tom:

> **Beryllium**
>
> Get FOUR Energy Pellets Orbiting TOM at the Same Time

You steal energy pellets by getting close to enemy drones and they orbit TOM for about one second before getting absorbed. Each drone starts with one pellet in front of and one behind it.

I guess that I have to steal those pellets in such a quick succession that 4 are orbiting TOM before getting absorbed, at least this is how I got the other achievements for 2 and 3 pellets orbiting at the same time. So far I've tried crossing points of a vertical and a horizontal drone, but either my timing was bad or it doesn't work this way.

If you got the achievement, in which level and with what strategy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Niban from the AVNT Steam Forums. I actually helped make the achievement, so here are tips and also a SP walkthrough:

- If TOM is moving without stopping, you have 3.5 tiles worth of time to grab 4 energy pellets.

  - So when you grab the first pellet, it would be 3.5 tiles worth of time before it is absorbed.
  - If you can grab 2 at once, it makes it easier to grab two more, but without a plan getting 4 will be difficult.
  - It's actually possible to get 5. I haven't been able to do 6 yet.
  - It's possible in 3.06 MP with placing a glitch to move a drone and doing a ridiculously tight path, but found it easier on 5.09 MP. (If you wait long enough on 5.09 MP you can go back and forth on the x-axis to grab from the front and backs of two drones parallel. )
  - Another strategy is to line up 4 drones and grab the pellets. If they are all traveling parallel to each other, it is only possible to grab from 3 drones, so we need them to be going in opposite directions so that we can escape. This is the strategy I use in SP.

**How to do it in 4.06 SP**

The hardest part is the timing, but you should be able to pull it off correctly in a few minutes. From the start, go down 1 tile and wait. The drone on the y-axis directly next to you (on your right) will be coming down. At the last second, hold "right" (don't let go!) to steal energy from the front of it. Three other drones will be lined up with it, and you will steal 4 energy in a span of 3 tiles. You will need to press "up" after the 4th drone if you don't want to die.

You will die a lot on the 2nd drone. If this is the case, you didn't wait long enough. You can cut it *really* close and still not get hit.

--

I hope that helps. If you need a video I can create one for you. I'll try to remember to check back. If you need more help and I haven't responded, post on the AVNT forums ( http://steamcommunity.com/app/207650/discussions/0/ ) and I'll see it.

Happy infecting!

Comment: Wow, thanks, I got it in the third try on 4.06 SP. Now I kinda regret asking, because now the achievement won't be so rare anymore ;). And thx for creating an account here extra for me :)

Comment: No problem! I've never visited here before so I imagine there are others like me who won't think to look here for the achievement. If you need help with any others, let me know.